# c# Read another applications listbox and sub listboxes?

Tags: c#, listview

How does one go about reading another applications listview and sub-listviews? This program has a main listview with a few other mini listviews once an item is clicked on the main view.

I want to create an application that can read the all of the listviews, how do I go about doing that? What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: How easy it is depends on what the other application is coded in. If it's using Win32, you can P/Invoke the FindWindow/VirtualAllocEx/GetWindowText/ReadProcessMemory functions and do it really easily.

Comment: Is the other application, the one you want to read from, being made by you?

Comment: @Renan Nope its a third party Windows application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this.

The supported way is to use an automation API like UIAutomation which is very simple to program. If the other application is using the standard Windows list view control then it should be accessible through UIAutomation. If the other application is using non-windowed controls (e.g. WPF, Qt) then you are dependent on the application implementing support for UIAutomation.

The other commonly attempted approach is to send windows messages to the list view control. This first of all involves enumerating the child windows of the application's main window in order to find the list view window. You can then send the control messages to obtain its contents. This sounds easy, but is actually rather tricky. The reason is that the messages require you to supply pointers to structures that are meaningful in the other process address space. This involves calls to `OpenProcess`, `VirtualAlloc`, `WriteProcessMemory`, `ReadProcessMemory` etc. It's quite tricky to get it right.

In my view, you should choose the automation API.